# How do I validate an input and change the target value if needed in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I want my text input the clear when I click it and start typing, similar to an Excel cell, and for my number input to clear if a non-number is entered, or to change to the last typed number if the value is above 24. The number part is working, where if I type 25, the value changes to 5 in the cell.

Because of the tabular nature of the data, I'd like to keep my data in arrays.

Basically, how do I bind `e.target.value` in my `changeInput` function to the variable the is bound with `bind:value={x}`?

Below is my complete code of how I've been trying it, but it's not working as I would hope.

```
    let jobNames = ['Job1', 'Job2', 'Job3']
    let jobHours = Array.from(Array(3), () => Array.from(Array(2)));    
    let cell = Array.from(Array(3), () => Array.from(Array(3)));
    let newText = true

    function changeInput(e) {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let input = value.slice(-1); 
        if (newText) {
      newText = false;
      e.target.value = input;
    }

    if (e.target.type === 'number') {
      if (!Number(input) && Number(input) !== 0) {
        e.target.value = '';
      }

      if (Number(value) > 24) {
        e.target.value = input;
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
        border-top: solid black 1px;
    border-left: solid black 1px;       
  }
  input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom: solid black 1px;
    border-right: solid black 1px;
    min-width: 50px;
  }
</style>

<container>
  {#each jobNames as name, i}
            <input
                type="text"
                data-cell={`${i}-0`}
                bind:this={cell[i][0]}
                                bind:value={name}
                on:input={changeInput}
                on:click={e => {newText = true; console.log(newText)}}
            />
        {#each jobHours[i] as hour, j}
            <input
                class="text-center"
                type="number"
                data-cell={`${i}-${j+1}`}
                bind:this={cell[i][j+1]}
                                bind:value={hour}
                on:input={changeInput}
                on:click={e => newText = true}
            />
        {/each} 
  {/each}
</container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the index from the template when the user types so we can access the bound element within the arrays `jobNames` and `jobHours`.

Here's how your code will now look

```
<script>
    // Declare variables here

    function changeInput(e, i, j) {
        const value = e.target.value;
        const input = e.data;

        if (newText) {
            newText = false;
            jobNames[i] = input;
        }

        if (!Number(input) && Number(input) !== 0) {
            console.log('entered');
            jobHours[i][j] = '';
        }

        if (Number(e.target.value) > 24) {
            jobHours[i][j] = input;
        }
    }
</script>

{#each jobNames as name, i}
    <input
        type="text"
        data-cell={`${i}-0`}
        bind:this={cell[i][0]}
        bind:value={name}
        on:input={e => changeInput(e, i)}
        on:click={e => {newText = true}}
    />
    {#each jobHours[i] as hour, j}
        <input
            class="text-center"
            type="text"
            data-cell={`${i}-${j+1}`}
            bind:this={cell[i][j+1]}
            bind:value={hour}
            on:input={e => changeInput(e, i, j)}
        />
    {/each} 
{/each}
```

Here is a working example on [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2fd5c80f5f504f9281dd7fb68d28daec?version=3.9.1).